# Autoincrement error in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

This message gives me when it makes the insert in the database and does not give any error only gives this warning message.

Advertencia:   The class RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork is already flushing. The query will be executed without further changes being written to the database.  If the query is conditional upon changed data the changes may not be reflected in the results.  Users should issue a flush() call upon completion of the dependent changes and prior to this flush() to ensure correct results.

```
    NclDocumento documento = null;
    try {
        NclTipoDocumento tipo = findTipoDocumentoById(tipoD.getValue());
        if (numero != null && numero != 0 && anioSelected != null) {
            documento = findAcuerdoByNumeroAndAnioAndTipoDocumento(numero, anioSelected, tipo);

            if (documento != null) {
                return new Response<>(documento, ResponseStatus.OK_INSERT);
            }

        }

        if (documento == null) {
            documento = new NclDocumento();
            documento.setNumero(122);
            documento.setAnio(2014);
            documento.setFechaEmision(new Date());
            documento.setIdTipoDocumento(em.find(NclTipoDocumento.class,1));
           if (firma != null && firma.getEmpleado() != null) {
               documento.setIdFirma(firma.getEmpleado());
            }
            documento.setFechaCreacion(new Date());
            documento.setUsuarioCreacion(usuarioLogueado);
            documento.setActivo(true);
        }

        em.persist(documento);
        em.flush();
        return new Response<>(documento, ResponseStatus.OK_INSERT);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        String validationError = getConstraintViolationExceptionAsString(ex);
        log.error(validationError);
        context.setRollbackOnly();
        return new Response<>(ResponseStatus.ERROR_PARAMS, "Sucedio un error con la información: " + validationError);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        processException(ex);
        context.setRollbackOnly();
        return new Response<>(ResponseStatus.ERROR, "Sucedio un error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Turn on logging to see what precedes and follows the warning to get an idea what might be involved.  Also look for persist/update events that might be executing queries.  Where is this code being executed from?

Comment: Well, if I already activate the log 4 and fine of my persistence but it does not show that insert

Comment: Want to show the JPA log then?  You didn't mention the provider, but I assume it is EclipseLink which would log this warning if calling flush within an event or operation triggered from flush.

Comment: If I use eclipselink but it does not show me the transaction, it's very strange that there were transactions in queue

Comment: I not clear on your comment. You can turn EclipseLink logging on as shown in the examples here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging but it depends on the server you are using. If using JTA, EclipseLink/JPA doesn't control the transactions and only registers with the JTA controller, so it wouldn't show the transaction itself, but would show any calls it makes within the transaction.  You cannot call flush outside of a transaction or you would get an exception.